# What Are Some Reasons a Field Cannot Be Accessed in Splunk eval Function

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

The following is my Splunk query.

```
index=o365 operation=Labels 
| table ProcessName Operations MessageTitle Application
| eval MessageTitle = if(isnull('MessageTitle') OR 'MessageTitle' == "" AND Application=="Outlook", 'EmailContents.Subject', 'MessageTitle')
```

The following is the search result:

```
{
  {
   Application:Excel
   ProcessName:Excel
   Operations:LabelUpdate
   MessageTitle:Test
  }
  {
   Application:Outlook
   ProcessName:
   Operations:LabelUpdate
   EmailContents:{
    from:person3
    subject: test mail
    to: person1
   }
  }
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to set the value of the field MessageTitle to the value of the field EmailContents.subject if the value of the field Application is Outlook using the eval function since EmailContents doesn't contain the field MessageTitle. The issue is for some reason EmailContents.subject cannot be accessed in eval. However, I noticed that I can use the eval function to set the value of the field ProcessName to the value of the field Application if the value of ProcessName is null in my table using the same method as I've shown in the code above. Please let me know What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it.

I have tried using case instead of an if statement but that didn't help. I also added host=* and source=* but that didn't help either

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that you could be running into:

First you have a [`table`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Table) command before your eval. This reporting command limits you to only the set of fields listed in the command. Because `EmailContents.subject` is not in your list of fields, it's not kept for the subsequent eval command to use.

(I'll note that best practices are you should tend to use the similar [`fields`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Fields) streaming command early in your search to help limit and state what fields you want to be available with your results at different points of your search, and only use `table` at the end when you're structuring your display... That said there is a search optimization that will replace table with fields... and fields would have the same problem, not listed fields = not available afterwards).

Secondly, your eval command references a field called `'EmailContents.Subject'` but your sample and your description reference `'EmailContents.subject'` these are two different fields as far as Splunk is concerned. Field names are always case sensitive in Splunk. (Field values on the other hand...  are case insensitive in `search`, case sensitive with `where` and `eval` clauses...)

Third... your sample data seems to have JSON objects within another JSON object... what are the actual boundaries of your events... you may need to talk to whomever has onboarded data to make sure each event is separate... Or you're dealing with various multivalue commands.

Hopefully these notes give you some ideas.

Comment: My search result is a JSON object containing many child objects and each child object contains almost all of the same fields that other child objects has except for the field ObjectId and EmailContents. Basically some child objects will have the ObjectId field but some will have the EmailContents field instead of ObjectId.

Comment: I have tried using the fields command by adding all the fields including EmailContents.subject which I need in my search results but the field EmailContents.subject is still not available for use in the eval function. You pointed out that EmailContents.subject and EmailContents.Subject are two different things but that was just a typo, they are the same thing.